# GHC options in cabal sandboxes

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I'm doing cabal builds in various sandboxes with different combinations of GHC options. The flags I'm interested in are `-O2`, `-O0`, `-threaded`, and `-feager-blackholing`.

Firstly, for which of these flags does it make sense to apply to all packages in the sandbox, and which should only apply to the final executable package? For example, I believe `-threaded` only affects linking.

Secondly, how do I tell cabal to apply a flag to all packages? I tried creating a `ghc-options:` line in the sandbox `cabal.config`, but it complained. I tried creating a `program-default-options` stanza in `cabal.config` (like the one in `~/.cabal/config`), but it complained about that too.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to apply these flags to all packages globally and may break things, let the ``ghc-options`` in each package's local cabal file decide the flags.

Comment: So if I apply `-O2` to my executable package, that's as good as applying `-O2` to all the packages?

Comment: @AshleyYakeley I may be wrong about this, but I believe that optimization occurs during the build step.  Once you're linking against pre-compiled binaries there isn't nearly as many optimizations that GHC can perform.  However, if you think that you have a package slowing you down, you can reinstall it with profiling enabled and see if that is actually the bottleneck and precisely where in that package you're getting slowed down.

Comment: So in that case, I want to build the entire sandbox with `-O2`, correct? How do I do that?